# When I run Next.js 13 with turbopack I get "TypeError: Class extends value #" but no error with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, turbopack

I have an app that uses Next.js 13. I have been running it with Turbopack and a few commits ago it stopped working. It now fails with a vague error. It says `TypeError: Class extends value #` in the browser, `Uncaught ReferenceError: $RefreshSig$ is not defined` in the browser console, `Error during SSR Rendering TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null`. This is what it looks like in the browser:
[image]

If I could just get a more specific error I could start to debug. The launch script in my package.json file looks like this for turbopack `"next dev --turbo --show-all"`

So how do I get a more specific traceable error?

Comment: do you have github repo. I haven't worked on next 13 turbo yet. I am curious about this error

Comment: I've isolated the error to 1 node module that I need for a project called `list-js-sdk`. I made this repo. Please follow the readme to throw the error https://github.com/ChristianOConnor/lit-protocol-nextjs-turbopack-fix.

Comment: I searched the issue and I think there is a circular dependency issue. somehow next.js-webpack handles this or maybe babel does not even create any circular dependency when transpiling. but next. js-turbo transpilation is causing circular dependency and cannot handle it

Comment: Oh that's amazing that you isolated it! Do you know about any fixes?

Comment: I need to know more about the turbo. that is the actual reason I asked for your repo.  I was scared of those issues. webpack is supported by the community via plugins. If there was an issue, one guy creates a plugin, submits to npm and issue is solved. I do not how turbo pack will solve the issues as we go

Comment: Here's turbopack's website https://turbo.build/pack, here is their github https://github.com/vercel/turbo, and here is the `lit-js-sdk` github page https://github.com/LIT-Protocol/lit-js-sdk. Is this what you need?

Comment: I got an error which is an open issue in github: https://github.com/vercel/turbo/issues/2361

Comment: [...]/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.mjs
      Error resolving commonjs request
      unable to resolve module "encoding"

Comment: Oh that's amazing! I wasn't able to trace the error so that's incredible that you were able to get the specific error. How did you throw it? Is it possible to share a screenshot? If not that's totally cool.

Comment: Run `yarn add encoding` in your project directory, to be honest it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two open github issues:

https://github.com/vercel/turbo/issues/2361

> [...]/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.mjs Error resolving commonjs
> request unable to resolve module "encoding"

I installed `encoding` inside the directory (I made some other changes but I forgot) and then I got another error:

[image]

It is an also has an open issue: https://github.com/vercel/turbo/issues/2372

From the last open issue, someone commented:

> I think there are a few issues being reported here.
>
> 1- Node stdlib requires/imports are failing

> 2- Highly dynamic requires/imports are failing

> I think we can get stdlib imports to work
> in SSR, and should stop that error from reporting. If you use it in
> client side, then we need to still warn.
>
> For the dynamic requires (it's using eval!), this is challenging to
> support. Again, we could just let node handle it, but that'll break if
> you're trying to do a relative require (this case requires a
> node_module, which would work ok).

I think this clearly explains the issue. turpopack will give us alot of headache.

Comment: Run `yarn add encoding` in your project directory, to be honest it resolved my issue.